# Keyboard backlight disabled in Virtual Box

Tags: virtualbox, keyboard

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 in my computer thanks to a virtual machine: VirtualBox. So I can use Windows 10 a Ubuntu in same time. I have installed updates proposed by the OS but I still have a problem, my keyboard have a backlighting but this one is disable when I use Ubuntu and I have no idea of how fix that.

Maybe somebody has a solution?

Comment: Is this in fullscreen or in windowed mode? Is there a keyboard shortcut to toggle the keyboard backlight that might have been disabled? Did you try with unselecting "Auto Capture Keyboard" in Virtual Box *Preferences > Input*?

Comment: I have found the problem thanks to your comment. I have unselected "Auto Capture Keyboard" and now I can able or disable the backlight of my keyboard.
Thank you very much !

Comment: Great! I made it an answer for others that may have a similar issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default Virtual Box will capture (almost) all keys from our keyboard. This may lead to unwanted effects for keys that control special functions, depending on hardware.

For these cases auto capturing can be disabled in Virtual Box general preferences:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Run this command in the directory where your VMs are stored, changing the "machine-name" for each file.

```
VBoxManage setextradata "<machine-name>" GUI/HidLedsSync "0"
```

Saw at: https://martinvanbeurden.nl/blog/virtualbox-numlock-weirdness/